# Step-up converter from 3.7 V to 12 V unable to supply the load

Tags: current, dc-dc-converter, load, step-up

I'm working on a project where I want to supply a magnetic valve powered by two parallel connected Li-ion batteries. Each battery has a voltage of 3.7 V (max. 4.2 V) with a capacity of 3.5 A (in total 7 A).

The magnetic valve need 12 VDC to operate and consumes 3.8 W (approx. 320 mA).

I'm using a [step up converter](https://www.amazon.de/ARCELI-Converter-Ausgangsspannung-Einstellbare-Step-Up-Platine/dp/B07BVWV74J) to boost the voltage from 3.7 V to 12 V.

My research includes the following points:

- the magnetic valve isn't working when I only use one battery.
- the magnetic valve is working fine if I use two batteries in parallel (capacity 7 A, 3.7 V). I assume that the maximum capacity has an impact on the consumer. Why?
- In my final circuit I use more components than just the magnetic valve (ESP32, 5 V relay, sensors, etc.). If I connect the other consumers the step-up converter is unable to supply the load for the magnetic valve anymore. Before the step up converter I measured 350 mA (which is fine), after the step up converter 100 mA. 100 mA is not enough to supply the magnetic valve and make it work.

Is the range of the step-up converter to boost from 3.7 V to 12 V simply too large to supply 3.8 W (320 mA)?
In different videos I learned that this step up converter should be used from 5 V up.

Is there any way to solve the issue with this step-up converter?

Comment: how about use the two batteries in series to give you the required more than 5 V input?

Comment: are you certain that the battery capacity is 3.5 `A` ?

Comment: Two batteries in series is working fine but now I need buck converter to reduce the voltage from 7,4 to 5V for other consumers... :/

Comment: I need to add that I want to charge the batteries by a solar panel. Means, I need an additional charge module. Charge modules operating with 2 batteries (7,4V) are very rare. Stay to 3,7V would be great.

Comment: I realized that there is no way around using 7.4V to supply the magnetic valve. I ordered all parts needed to make it work. Thanks for your input!

Comment: Your Lithium-Ion batteries at only 3.7V are almost dead. Their capacity is measured when they are fully charged at 4.2V each and when their charging current has dropped to a low amount.

Answer (score 0):

> In different videos I learned that this step-up converter should be used from 5V and above.

Yes.  "Optimal operating voltage range: 5 V to 30 V"

Something like [this](https://www.befr.ebay.be/itm/323236694668?hash=item4b42688a8c:g:-qYAAOSwMsVXjKIH&amdata=enc%3AAQAHAAAA8OpYULPvSgl0i5FqsEgrUxE84Hp5r0OuXmOHqiy%2BxoxtU8rExZHL9WbgBxNeV2jdCn5yKVJlIPEc8hLJPexExvEf2ZNRYSILYUbceDznqD%2B66g1anbp3s2QYGdAqjnM4%2FSUugtmGMRvtss2ehphURElnYI3nwWF4eZWGyACNkkJTtOIoavTyUSuAluWwX7zceCqHy48IUjYPIR4PY483od%2FnsAGcUq5GDFLRptyl9W7pRHFwmXS4pLIeE7G1llJZgSPU3IEmRtr140h6rSyTUqitsk8AC0RVsuM4BnVcDeI%2FD504Mg8KmM6E59OKSPyfKg%3D%3D%7Ctkp%3ABk9SR_Lnp6PzYA) could be better, from 2V ...
Made with MT3608.

Comment: I tried the MT3608 but it's not working. I can even hear an unhealthy beeping. ^^

Comment: Ok. Will check it.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution for you. Because I used it on 2019.enter image description here

[image]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).